# MFMailComposeViewController from a popup

Tags: ipad, uipopovercontroller

I have a UIViewController displayed as a popup in my iPad app. Within it, I have a button that triggers MFMailComposeViewController to send email. However, it currently doesn't seem to do anything, even though if I make that view controller not a popup, it works fine. My guess is that this is because I'm trying to trigger one modal screen from another, so my question: is there a way to do this? What's the acceptable interaction here?

If I try to dismiss my modal popup first and then display the MFMailComposeViewController, it dismisses the popup and nothing happens. I tried to push the top view controller of MFMailComposeViewController, since it's a UINavigationController, onto my popup's navigation controller, and I got the navigation bar updated to the right thing but no controls. It also crashed when I clicked cancel:

```
-[NSPathStore2 _closeButtonClicked:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc602f70
(gdb) bt
0  0x020fa2f9 in objc_exception_throw ()
1  0x01fa80bb in -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] ()
2  0x01f17966 in ___forwarding___ ()
3  0x01f17522 in __forwarding_prep_0___ ()
4  0x008994fd in -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] ()
5  0x00aabcc3 in -[UIBarButtonItem(UIInternal) _sendAction:withEvent:] ()
6  0x008994fd in -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] ()
7  0x00929799 in -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] ()
8  0x0092bc2b in -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] ()
9  0x0092a7d8 in -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] ()
10 0x008bdded in -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] ()
11 0x0089ec37 in -[UIApplication sendEvent:] ()
12 0x008a3f2e in _UIApplicationHandleEvent ()
13 0x02597992 in PurpleEventCallback ()
14 0x01f87944 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ ()
15 0x01ee7cf7 in __CFRunLoopDoSource1 ()
16 0x01ee4f83 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
17 0x01ee4840 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
18 0x01ee4761 in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
19 0x025961c4 in GSEventRunModal ()
20 0x02596289 in GSEventRun ()
21 0x008a7c93 in UIApplicationMain ()
22 0x00002c9e in main (argc=1, argv=0xbffff000) at /Users/abushnaq/AccurevWorkspaces/Future_Core_Integration_iphone/iPhoneClient/main.m:15
```

and none of this stacktrace is in code that I wrote.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The key was to dismiss the previous modal control **without animation**. If I animated the dismissal of the first one, the second one never showed up. I'm guessing the async nature of animations is the reason behind that.